# How to create a delegate for a generic method?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, delegates

I have a simple class:

```
class Test
{
    public static int Test<T>(T arg)
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

I would like to get an object of type `Delegate` that represents this method. Is it possible to create such a delegate? It would be even better if I could turn a method with any number of parameters and generic arguments into a `Delegate`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? How would you use such a delegate?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, I'm going to inspect it via Reflection and emit a code that invokes it.

Comment: Why the delegate then in the first place? Why not inspect the method directly?

Comment: So that I can have a single universal method, something like `void ImportMethod(string name, Delegate code)` that imports any kind of method into the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to use a delegate here. You want a [`MethodInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.aspx) instance:

```
void ImportMethod(string name, MethodInfo method)
```

You would call it like this:

```
void ImportMethod("Test", typeof(Test).GetMethod("Test", ...Static));
```

Comment: So the user will have to use Reflection to get the `MethodInfo` for the method?

Comment: @Impworks: Yes. You might be able to simplify this a bit by providing helper methods.

Answer (score 1):

If you write the method using generics to keep type safety, you will need to write two methods for each method having a different amount of input parameters, one for a void method (Action) and one for a method returning a value (Func).
I threw in a helper class because it cuts down on number of generic parameters you have to pass for each method import. It also helps with intellisense when calling the method.

```
    public class Foo
    {
        public void Bar()
        {
        }

        public void Bar(string input)
        {
        }

        public bool BarReturn()
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public class ImportHelper<TClass>
    {
        public void Import(string name, Expression<Action<TClass>> methodExpression)
        {
            ImportMethod(name, methodExpression);
        }

        public void ImportMethodWithParam<TParam>(string name, Expression<Action<TClass, TParam>> methodExpression)
        {
            ImportMethod<TClass, TParam>(name, methodExpression);
        }

        public void ImportMethodWithResult<TResult>(string name, Expression<Func<TClass, TResult>> methodExpression)
        {
            ImportMethod<TClass, TResult>(name, methodExpression);
        }
    }

    private static void TestImport()
    {
        ImportMethod<Foo>("MyMethod", f => f.Bar());
        ImportMethod<Foo, string>("MyMethod1", (f, p) => f.Bar(p));
        ImportMethod<Foo, bool>("MyMethod2", f => f.BarReturn());

        var helper = new ImportHelper<Foo>();
        helper.Import("MyMethod", f => f.Bar());
        helper.ImportMethodWithParam<string>("MyMethod1", (f, p) => f.Bar(p));
        helper.ImportMethodWithResult("MyMethod2", f => f.BarReturn());
    }

    public static void ImportMethod<TClass>(string name, Expression<Action<TClass>> methodExpression)
    {
        var method = GetMethodInfo(methodExpression.Body as MethodCallExpression);
        //Do what you want with the method.
    }

    public static void ImportMethod<TClass, TParam>(string name, Expression<Action<TClass, TParam>> methodExpression)
    {
        var method = GetMethodInfo(methodExpression.Body as MethodCallExpression);
        //Do what you want with the method.
    }

    public static void ImportMethod<TClass, TResult>(string name, Expression<Func<TClass, TResult>> methodExpression)
    {
        var method = GetMethodInfo(methodExpression.Body as MethodCallExpression);
        //Do what you want with the method.
    }

    private static MethodInfo GetMethodInfo(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
    {
        if (methodCallExpression == null)
            return null;

        return methodCallExpression.Method;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like [Func](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx) and [Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx) are what you are looking for.

You could use the following to get a "delegate object"

```
Func<int> func = () => Test<Foo>(bar);
```

You could use

```
void ImportMethod(string name, Action action)
```

or

```
void ImportMethod(string name, Func<int> func)
```

depending on whether you need the return value and register like this

```
ImportMethod("Name", () => Test<Foo>(bar))
```

Comment: This way I lose the genericness of the method.

Comment: @Impworks I dont understand what you mean. You still have the generics when you are registering it, but in the method that calls the delegate it only cares that it returns a int. Or else you are probably trying to know to much in that method. How would you know what to pass in to each method? how to call them?

Answer (score 0):

```
public delegate int Del<T>(T item);
```

Comment: This creates a delegate type, while I want an _object_ of type `System.Delegate`.